# c++ pointer declaration and assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

```
int num1 = 8;   //okay
int *pointer;   //okay
*pointer = &num1;   //NOT okay, compiler says (Error:a value of type int* cannot be
                    //assigned to an entity of type "int")

int num2 = 8;   //okay
int *pointer = &num2;   //okay
```

I am confused why the first part gives an error and the 2nd part doesnt, they look the same to me

Comment: Change it to `pointer = &num1`, as the type of `pointer` is `int*` and the type of `&num1` is also `int*` (while the type of `*pointer` is `int`).

Comment: `*` and `&` have different meaning depending on the context. In a declaration they mean pointer type and reference type, in an expression they are the dereference and address of operators

Comment: `int *pointer = X;` means: `int *pointer;  pointer = X;`

Answer (score 6):

In the assignment statement:

```
*pointer = &num1;   //NOT okay
```

`*pointer` is the value that `pointer` points to, of type `int`, and `&num1` is the address of `num1`, of type `int*`. As the compiler says, you can't assign a pointer to an integer.

`pointer = &num1` or `*pointer = num1` would both be fine, depending on whether you want to modify the pointer itself, or the value it points to.

In the declaration:

```
int *pointer = &num2;   //okay
```

Despite the similar appearance to the assignment statement, this initialises `pointer` not `*pointer`. It declares `pointer` to be a pointer, of the same type `int*` as `&num2`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * in third line. It returns the value stored at position/address currently stored in variable pointer and interprets it as int.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `&` gives a pointer to the variable over which is acting.
`&num1` is a pointer to `int` (since `num1` has type `int`) which points to the address of `num1`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear: The expression `*pointer` is of type `int` and the expression `&num1` is of type `int*`. Those two types are not compatible (you try to assign a pointer to a non-pointer).

When you use the dereference operator `*` on a pointer, you get what the pointer is pointing to, and if you use the address-of operator `&` you get the address of (i.e. pointer to) something.

To make `pointer` point to a variable, then just assign to it:

```
pointer = &num1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *pointer = &num2;
```

is the same as

```
int *pointer;
pointer = &num2;
```

not

```
int *pointer;
*pointer = &num2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is more of a general description rather than a direct answer to your question...

If you declare a variable of some type, then you can also declare another variable pointing to it.

For example:

`int a;`

`int* b = &a;`

There are two ways to "look at" variable `b` **(that's what probably confuses most beginners)**:

- You can consider `b` as a variable of type `int*`.
- You can consider `*b` as a variable of type `int`.

Hence, some programmers would declare `int* b`, whereas others would declare `int *b`.

But the fact of the matter is that these two declarations are identical (the spaces are meaningless).

You can use either `b` as a pointer to an integer value, or `*b` as the actual pointed integer value.

You can read the pointed value (e.g., `int c = *b`) and write the pointed value (e.g., `*b = 5`).